# Weak reference to a scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, structure, weak-ptr, scoped-ptr

Generally I follow the Google style guide, which I feel aligns nicely with the way I see things.  I also, almost exclusively, use boost::scoped_ptr so that only a single manager has ownership of a particular object.  I then pass around naked pointers, the idea being that my projects are structured such that the managers of said objects are always destroyed after the objects that use them are destroyed.

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Smart_Pointers

This is all great, however I was just bitten by a nasty little memory stomp bug where the owner just so happened to be deleted before objects that were using it were deleted.

Now, before everyone jumps up and down that I'm a fool for this pattern, why don't I just use shared_ptr ? etc., consider the point that I don't want to have undefined owner semantics.  Although shared_ptr would have caught this particular case, it sends the wrong message to users of the system.  It says, "I don't know who owns this, it could be you!"

What would have helped me would have been a weak pointer to a scoped pointer.  In effect, a scoped pointer that has a list of weak references, that are nulled out when the scoped pointer destructs.  This would allow single ownership semantics, but give the using objects a chance to catch the issue I ran into.

So at the expense of an extra 'weak_refs' pointer for the scoped_ptr and an extra pointer for the 'next_weak_ptr' in the weak_ptr, it would make a neat little single owner, multiple user structure.

It could maybe even just be a debug feature, so in 'release' the whole system just turns back into a normally sized scoped_ptr and a standard single pointer for the weak reference.

So..... my QUESTIONS after all of this are:

1. Is there such a pointer/patten already in stl/boost that I'm
   missing, or should I just roll my own?
2. Is there a better way, that
   still meets my single ownership goal?

Cheers,
Shane

Comment: I do not know of a standard or library implementation. If you do implement what you've described you'll end up with an implementation that is very similar to boost shared_ptr/weak_ptr stuff as you probably want to detect the case where somebody has gotten the raw pointer out of the weak_ptr and cached it. Having said that you may just want to use shared_ptr/weak_ptr and assert in your "manager" that the shared_ptr it is keeping is unique when you want to destroy the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 2. Is there a better way, that still meets my single ownership goal?

Do use a `shared_ptr`, but as a class member so that it's part of the invariant of that class and the public interface only exposes a way to obtain a `weak_ptr`.

Of course, pathological code can then retain their own `shared_ptr` from that `weak_ptr` for as long as they want. I don't recommend trying to protect against Machiavelli here, only against Murphy (using Sutter's words). On the other hand, if your use case is asynchronous, then the fact that locking a `weak_ptr` returns a `shared_ptr` may be a feature!

Comment: That's actually a nice way to hide the ownership issue.  I like it :)

Answer (score 3):

> Although shared_ptr would have caught this particular case, it sends the wrong message to users of the system. It says, "I don't know who owns this, it could be you!"

A shared_ptr doesn't mean "I don't know who owns this". It means "*We* own this." Just because one entity does not have exclusive ownership does not mean that *anyone* can own it.

The purpose of a shared_ptr is to ensure that the pointer cannot be destroyed until everyone who shares it is in agreement that it ought to be destroyed.

> Is there such a pointer/patten already in stl/boost that I'm missing, or should I just roll my own?

You could use a shared_ptr exactly the same way you use a scoped_ptr. Just because it can be shared doesn't mean you *have* to share it. That would be the easiest way to work; just make single-ownership a convention rather than an API-established rule.

However, if you need a pointer that is single-owner and yet has weak pointers, there isn't one in Boost.

Comment: Hi Nicol, yes I was being somewhat melodramatic in my "I don't know who owns this..." line, but yes, you're right ;)  As to you point, I am starting to to rethink my practice of enforcing single ownership and just rolling with the shared_ptr approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that weak pointers would help that much.  Typically, if a
component X uses another component Y, X must be informed of Y's demise,
not just to nullify the pointer, but perhaps to remove it from a list,
or to change its mode of operation so that it no longer needs the
object.  Many years ago, when I first started C++, there was a flurry of
activity trying to find a good generic solution.  (The problem was
called relationship management back then.)  As far as I know, no good
generic solution was every found; at least, every project I've worked on
has used a hand built solution based on the Observer pattern.

I did have a `ManagedPtr` on my site, when it was still up, which behaved
about like what you describe.  In practice, except for the particular
case which led to it, I never found a real use for it, because
notification was always needed.  It's not hard to implement, however;
the managed object derives from a `ManagedObject` class, and gets all of
the pointers (`ManagedPtr`, and not raw pointers) it hands out from it.
The pointer itself is registered with the `ManagedObject` class, and the
destructor of the `ManagedObject` class visits them all, and "disconnects"
them by setting the actual pointer to null.  And of course, `ManagedPtr`
has an `isValid` function so that the client code can test before
dereferencing.  This works well (regardless of how the object is
managed—most of my entity objects "own" themselves, and do a
`delete this` is response to some specific input), except that you tend
to leak invalid `ManagedPtr` (e.g. whenever the client keeps the pointer
in a container of some sort, because it may have more than one), and
clients still aren't notified if they need to take some action when your
object dies.

Comment: Hi James, I've implemented a similar container before which effectively zeros out all references/pointers after calling a function like "objectDeleting" function.  It's really just the Observer Pattern.  I'm starting to think it's not really necessary for my manager case too.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using QT, `QPointer` is basically a weak pointer to a `QObject`.  It connects itself to the "I just got destroyed" event in the pointed-to value, and invalidates itself automatically as needed.  That's a seriously hefty library to pull in for what amounts to bug tracking, though, if you aren't already jumping through QT's hoops.